# Можно ли в google sheets закрепить область просмотра для каждого пользователя и сохранять ее при очередном входе?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-docs

Есть таблица шириной 500 ячеек. Пользователь_1 постоянно работает со столбцом 400.
Пользователь_2 постоянно работает со столбцом 300. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при открытии таблицы у пользователя_1 сразу открывалось окно с областью столбца 400, а у пользователя_2 - со столбцом 300?

Answer (score 0):

Да, такое **можно сделать**, если использовать ссылки с параметрами и в параметрах точно указывать требуемый столбец.

Допустим к примеру, что Пользователю_1 в начале работы всегда нужен столбец 400. Если я правильно посчитал, адрес этого столбца `OJ:OJ`. Тогда Пользователь_1 для открытия таблиц должен использовать следующую ссылку:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<идентификатор_файла>/edit#gid=<идентификатор_листа>&range=OJ:OJ`

Для простоты можно указать всего одну ячейку -

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<идентификатор_файла>/edit#gid=<идентификатор_листа>&range=OJ1`

Подробнее о ссылках такого типа можно прочесть, например, [здесь](https://cpab.ru/kak-poluchit-giperssylku-na-yachejku-ili-diapazon-v-google-sheets/). Не забудьте указать правильные идентификаторы в предоставляемых пользователям ссылках и проверить их в деле.